# How to show selected class details in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sidebar

I am listing all projects in side bar. Initially for first it will show empty window in browser after selecting project from side bar, it will display project details of project selected one.

here is screenshot i need as result:

[image]

Right now i can able to display details of selected project form side menu but while clicking on next project previous selected projects also adding in currently selected one.

How can i show details selected project details from side bar menu?

Here is the code used for: To show project list and details.

```js
$(function() {
  $('ul.nav a').on('click', function() {
    var pjname = $(this).attr('name');
    $(this).parent().parent().find('a.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#' + pjname).toggleClass('d-none');
  });
});


// Get the container element
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("projectlist");

// Get all buttons with class="btn" inside the container
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");

// Loop through the buttons and add the active class to the current/clicked button
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
      <div id="projectlist" class="sidebar-sticky">
        <ul class="nav flex-column nav-pills">

          {{range .Projects}}
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a name="{{.ProjectID}}" class="nav-link" href="#">

              <img class="img-fluid" style="width:8%" src="static/image/generic_gcp.png"> {{.Name}}

              <div>
                <small>
                    ProjectId: {{.ProjectID}}
                  </small>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          {{end}}

        </ul>

        <!-- Might need this seperator
            <h6 class="sidebar-heading d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center px-3 mt-4 mb-1 text-muted">
              <span>Savings Reports</span>
            </h6>
          -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 pt-3 px-4">
      {{range .Projects}}

      <div id={{.ProjectID}} class="d-none justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom ">
        <h1 class="h2">Project:{{.Name}}</h1>

        <!-- This pushes right
    <div class="btn-toolbar mb-2 mb-md-0">    </div>
-->

        <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
          <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Compute API Enabled</button>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="Second group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Service Account Key</button>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Third group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Other Errors</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr>


        <div class="container">

          <table class="table table-striped h6">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Type</th>
                <th scope="col">GCP Zone</th>
                <th scope="col">Startup</th>
                <th scope="col">Shutdown</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {{range .Instances}}
              <tr>
                <td>{{.Name}}</th>
                  <td>{{.Type | baseUrl}}</td>
                  <td>{{.Zone | baseUrl}}</td>
                  <td>


                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
                      <button id="startHour" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">hour</button>

                      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="startHour">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">3</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">4</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">5</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">6</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">7</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">8</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">9</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">10</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">11</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">12</a>
                      </div>
                      <span style="color:white; background-color:#5A6268">:</span>
                      <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
                        <button id="startMinute" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">min</button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="startMinute">
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">00</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">05</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">10</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">15</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">20</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">25</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">30</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">35</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">40</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">45</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">50</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">55</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-toggle-time" data-toggle="collapse" href="#">am</button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">zone</button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Set</button>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">hour</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">min</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">am</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">zone</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Set</button>
                    </div>

                  </td>

              </tr>
              {{end}}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

        <!--
              <div class="btn-group mr-2">
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Share</button>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Export</button>
              </div>

              <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle">
                <span data-feather="calendar"></span>
                This week
              </button>
              -->






      </div>
      {{end}}
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a **working** [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)? It will much easier for us to help you.

Comment: @MoshFeu Give me moment..

Comment: @MoshFeu hey i have updated. can you check out issue pls

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But it's not **working**. I need to see it as the way it works on your local environment.

Comment: @M project lsit are getting from json